# Integration_Deduction of a Reduction formula

Tags: integration

If $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}(a\cos\theta+b \sin\theta)^n d\theta$, then show that $n I_n=ab(a^{n-2}+b^{n-2})+(n-1)(a^2+b^2)I_{n-2}$, where $n(\ge 2)$ is a positive integer.   
 My attempt is as follows: $$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}(a\cos\theta+b \sin\theta)^n d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2}(a\cos\theta+b \sin\theta)^{n-1}(a\cos\theta+b \sin\theta)d\theta=(a\cos\theta+b \sin\theta)^{n-1}(a\sin\theta-b \cos\theta)\Bigg\vert_0^{\pi/2}-$$ $$(n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}(a\cos\theta+b \sin\theta)^{n-2}(-a \sin \theta+b \cos \theta)((a\sin\theta-b \cos\theta) d\theta$$ (by-parts integration)$$=a b^{n-1}+a^{n-1}b+(n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}(a\cos\theta+b \sin\theta)^{n-2}(a \sin\theta-b\cos\theta)^2d\theta$$ 
 Is it correct ? Then how can I proceed? Please help me. Thanks in advance for any kind of hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from where you left off, we have

$$I_n = ab(a^{n-2} + b^{n-2}) + (n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2} \left( a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta \right)^{n-2} (a \sin \theta - b\cos \theta)^2 \, d \theta $$

The coefficients are in front of the wrong trigonometric functions in the quadratic factor in the integrand, so we'll expand it, then use the identity $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ **to switch them**.

$$\begin{align}
(a \sin \theta - b \cos \theta)^2 &= a^2 \sin^2 \theta - 2ab \sin \theta \cos \theta + b^2\cos^2 \theta \\
&= a^2 \sin^2 \theta - 2ab \sin \theta \cos \theta + b^2\cos^2 \theta \\
&= a^2 (1-\cos^2 \theta) - 2ab \sin \theta \cos \theta + b^2(1- \sin^2 \theta)\\
&= (a^2+b^2) - (a\cos \theta + b \sin \theta)^2 
\end{align}$$

Plugging that into the above integral and distributing gives us

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \left( a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta \right)^{n-2} \left[ (a^2+b^2) - (a\cos \theta + b \sin \theta)^2 \right] \, d \theta $$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \left( a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta \right)^{n-2} (a^2+b^2) \, d \theta - \int_0^{\pi/2} (a\cos \theta + b \sin \theta)^n \, d \theta $$
$$= (a^2+b^2)I_{n-2}  - I_n$$

Finally, with a bit of rearranging we get

$$I_n = ab(a^{n-2} + b^{n-2}) + (n-1)(a^2+b^2)I_{n-2}  - (n-1)I_n$$
$$nI_n = ab(a^{n-2} + b^{n-2}) + (n-1)(a^2+b^2)I_{n-2}$$

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help.